# Regular Expression for website URL - no HTTP(s)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression to work where the following URLs are accepted:

```
www.somesite.com
somesite.com
www.somesite.ca
somesite.ca
somesite.cu.sk.ca
www.somsite.cu.sk.ca
somesite.sk.ca
www.somesite.sk.ca
```

I have the following so far but it allows www.somesite

```
 ^(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}.[a-zA-Z]{2})(.[a-zA-z]{2})?$
```

Query strings, http, https, ftp are not in play here. Thanks!

Comment: why use regex for this?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to escape `.` in the last pattern `(.[a-zA-z]{2})` (the dot will match any character):

```
^(www\.)?[\w-]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[a-zA-Z]{2}.[a-zA-Z]{2})(\.[a-zA-z]{2})?$
                                                         ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/25)

Also, I replaced your `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]` with its equivalent `[\w-]`

Comment: Business requirements @Josh Stevens